# Using String.Indexes as integers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a playground in Xcode that looks like this

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

var url = "app://Wip%20My_Hair_Willow%20Smith_0_Tue%20May%2019%202015%2021:34:51%20GMT-0400%20(EDT)"

var info = url.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("whenisay://", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%20", withString: " ", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("_", withString: "/", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

var SlashOne = info.rangeOfString("/")!.startIndex
var SlashTwo = dropFirst(info.substringFromIndex(SlashOne)).rangeOfString("/")!.startIndex
var SlashThree = dropFirst(info.substringFromIndex(SlashTwo)).rangeOfString("/")!.startIndex
var SlashFour = dropFirst(info.substringFromIndex(SlashThree)).rangeOfString("/")!.startIndex
```

I want to then write this:

```
let first = info.substringToIndex(advance(info.startIndex, SlashOne))
```

So that I can have a substring of just before the first "/" in `info`, but it's giving me the error:

```
Cannot find an overload for 'advance' that accepts an argument list of type '(String.Index, String.Index)'
```

This last line works if I replace `SlashOne` with an integer so I can only assume that 'advance' wants `'(String.Index, Int)'`.

How can I turn `SlashOne` into an integer? I can't find it anywhere. Can you even do that? If not, how could I split this string up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to split a string is this

```
let array = split(info){$0 == "/"}
```

This will return an array

```
let first = splitedarray[0]//app:
let second = splitedarray[1]//Wip My
```

If you insist to use your way,you can get a substring in this way

```
let firstRange = Range<String.Index>(start: info.startIndex, end:SlashOne)
let first = info.substringWithRange(firstRange)//This is app:
```